# Location of Coldfusion connection string settings

Tags: coldfusion

This is new to me: I am looking into a ColdFusion website.

The problem is I cannot even find the connection string. In some qryXXX.cfm files, I find

```
<cfquery name="GetXXX" datasource="xxxx">
```

But I just cannot find where this datasource is stored.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The datasource is defined in the ColdFusion Administrator.

On a default developer install the CF Administrator is available at:

`http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm`
<sub>(On a server, it may or not be configured differently to this.)</sub>

Once logged in, on the left hand menu, go to section "Data & Services", and the first entry is "Data Sources", which is the area you want to go in.

Within this area, you will find a list of all defined datasources - the first icon in the Actions column lets you edit/view the details.

The actual data which the CF Administrator works with is stored in `{coldfusion-dir}/lib/neo-datasource.xml`

Comment: You need to log into the CF Admin, click on "datasources" and "add" a datasource. As Richard has said.

Comment: My website is located on an IIS server. There is no CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm or whatever. And I don't think ColdFusion has been installed on this machine.

Comment: If CF isn't even installed on the server, then you have larger problems than not being able to find the datasource.  Typically the CFIDE directory is a virtual directory in IIS. It is unlikely to be an actual directory in your source code, though that is possible.

Comment: If ColdFusion (or another CFML engine) isn't installed then the code wont do anything, so your first step then needs to be to install one. 

If your code _does_ run then to locate the config files, do `<cfdump abort var=#Server# />` - the cf root should be in `Server.ColdFusion.RootDir` variable.

Answer (score 0):

in coldfusion 7 this file is called neo-query.xml
and is stored, in a jrun install, at

C:\Apps\JRun4\servers\cfusion\cfusion-ear\cfusion-war\WEB-INF\cfusion\lib

the path may differ slightly depending on your install